# Calculo com Javascript dá erro

Tags: javascript

Galera, o meu programa faz uma série de cálculos, no entanto há um que não funciona e não já não tenho mais ideias de como o resolver.

Os cáclculos são estes:

```
 function calculaResultado(x){        
        console.log(x);
        a = document.getElementById('avInicial' + x).value;
        b = document.getElementById('meta' + x).value;
        c = document.getElementById('avFinal' + x).value;

        let resultado = ((c*100)/b);

        if(b === c){
            resultado = 100; //100%
        } else if (a > c) {
            resultado = 0; // 0%
        } 
        else {
            resultado = parseInt(resultado);
        }

        document.getElementById('resultado' + x).value =  resultado; 

        calculaMediaFinal();
        ContaObjetivos();
        ContaConcluidos();
        Totalmente();
    }

    function calculaMediaFinal() {
      let soma = 0;
      let contador = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) { 
        if (document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value) {
          soma += parseInt(document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value, 10);
          contador++;
        }
      }
      var media = soma / contador;
      var inputCuboMedia = document.getElementById('ConcretizaObj');
      inputCuboMedia.value = parseInt(media, 10);
    }

    function ContaObjetivos(){
        let contador = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
            if (document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value) {
          contador++;
        }
    }var inputCount = document.getElementById('ObjDefinidos');
    inputCount.value = parseInt(contador,10);
    }

    function ContaConcluidos(){
        let contador = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
            if ((document.getElementById('resultado' + i).value) == 100) {
          contador++;
            } 
        }
        var inputAting = document.getElementById('ObjAtingidos');
        inputAting.value = parseInt(contador,10);
    }

    function Totalmente(){
         def = document.getElementById('ObjDefinidos');
         atin = document.getElementById('ObjAtingidos');


        var valor = atin / def;
        var inputdivisao = document.getElementById('TotalAlcancados');
        inputdivisao.value = parseFloat(valor, 10);
    }
```

A função que não funciona é a última: resultado é: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem ver se descobrem o motivo desse NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou acrescentar `.value` ao selecionar os elementos:

```
def = document.getElementById('ObjDefinidos').value;
atin = document.getElementById('ObjAtingidos').value;
```

Da forma que está, apenas está selecionando os elementos em si, e não seus valores.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou :)